# 404 Error Page Not Working

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I have a new page, I made a custom folder, with a html 404 template and everything, I just added this:

```html
ErrorDocument 404 /404/index.html
```

to my **.htaccess** file. I can load my 404 template page manually (And it looks great)
But when I load the 404 from a 404 error, I see this. 
[Screenshot!](http://gyazo.com/7350bbe951456300c2fc4d18ce8fea1c)
My 404 page: http://agucova.esy.es/404/index.html
What could be wrong?

EDIT: When I get a 404 error from the /404/ directory (where the template is) it works.

Comment: Provide us any code. We cannot help you. Though you answered yourself you could have edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the thing is, the page was loading as local, but the html is writed so it loads images and css's from /css/index.css not http://agucova.esy.es/404/css/index.css
That simple is it!